# Is the word start a usable field name in a Django model?

Tags: django, modelform

I have a model called Order with a datetime field called start. I can read and write from/to that field no problem.

However, I just created a ModelForm and specified start as one of the fields=() in Meta and I get:

```
Unknown field(s) (start) specified for Order
```

I've made sure it is not a typo by copying and pasting the field name. If I remove that field, it works.

Here is the exact ModelForm

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('details', 'start', 'quantity', 'total')
```

**EDIT added more details:**

I tried using exclude = () to exclude all fields except those I need, and start does not appear in the form even though I don't exclude it.

Here is the model:

```
class Order(MyModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, )
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, )
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, )
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null    =True, )
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, )
    misc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, )
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, )
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True, )
    end = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, blank=True, null=True, )
    duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, )
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, )
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, )
    details = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, )
    configured = models.BooleanField(default=False, )
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `start1` (just to check if the problem is indeed the specific word "start")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the auto_now_add=True and the problem is solved.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
auto_now_add=True
```

[Model field reference | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) :

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True
>   will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have `editable=False` defined for the `start` field?

According to documentation:

> If `False`, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other `ModelForm`. Default is `True`.

Comment: Thanks but I specifically had editable=True set. I've just tried removing that (leaving the default) and no change.